# Drivers are not recognize on Windows 10 v1903

Tags: usb, drivers, network-printer, windows-10-v1903

Yesterday I had to install two TCP/IP printers in my PC.
If I want to print any type of file, I can do it with the correct program but, if I want to change the name of the printer from the control panel, in Windows 10, version 1903, I can't do it because there are not in the Windows page.
I have already clear the spooler, reboot the PC, do an hard reset of it but nothing happens.
Can anyone help me?

---

**UPDATES**
Today I connected an external disk reader to a new PC that is 1903 version and it is not recognized.
It is not recognized in a 1809 version of Windows 10 too. 
Instead everything works correctly on the 1803 version.
Is there any updates of Windows that corrupts the Drivers recognize?
I hope I was clear in the explanation but I absolutely need an indication towards where to move in this problem.

Comment: can you "ping" the printers by their IP adress?

Comment: The printer page in settings is still borked, but the Devices and Printers in good old Control Panel is not. Have you tried adding them from there?

Comment: Yes, I can ping the printers, in fact I can print.
@LPChip I installed the printers right from the old control panel.

Comment: So its solved? I can write you an answer so you can mark it as solved. :) Want that?

Comment: I cannot see the printers in the old control panel though I installed them from here